# what is slowing down this webpage in my local server?

Tags: jquery, html, css

This is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mitchbregs/ErDgF/)

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".red").click(function(){
        $(".red").addClass("selected");
        $(".orange").removeClass("selected");
        $(".yellow").removeClass("selected");
        $(".green").removeClass("selected");
        $(".lightblue").removeClass("selected");
        $(".darkblue").removeClass("selected");
        $(".pink").removeClass("selected");
        $(".brown").removeClass("selected");
        $(".black").removeClass("selected");
        $(".white").removeClass("selected");
    });
    $(".orange").click(function(){
        $(".orange").addClass("selected");
        $(".red").removeClass("selected");
        $(".yellow").removeClass("selected");
        $(".green").removeClass("selected");
        $(".lightblue").removeClass("selected");
        $(".darkblue").removeClass("selected");
        $(".pink").removeClass("selected");
        $(".brown").removeClass("selected");
        $(".black").removeClass("selected");
        $(".white").removeClass("selected");
    });
    $(".yellow").click(function(){
        $(".yellow").addClass("selected");
        $(".orange").removeClass("selected");
        $(".red").removeClass("selected");
        $(".green").removeClass("selected");
        $(".lightblue").removeClass("selected");
        $(".darkblue").removeClass("selected");
        $(".pink").removeClass("selected");
        $(".brown").removeClass("selected");
        $(".black").removeClass("selected");
        $(".white").removeClass("selected");
    });
    $(".green").click(function(){
        $(".green").addClass("selected");
        $(".orange").removeClass("selected");
        $(".yellow").removeClass("selected");
        $(".red").removeClass("selected");
        $(".lightblue").removeClass("selected");
        $(".darkblue").removeClass("selected");
        $(".pink").removeClass("selected");
        $(".brown").removeClass("selected");
        $(".black").removeClass("selected");
        $(".white").removeClass("selected");
    });
    $(".lightblue").click(function(){
        $(".lightblue").addClass("selected");
        $(".orange").removeClass("selected");
        $(".yellow").removeClass("selected");
        $(".green").removeClass("selected");
        $(".red").removeClass("selected");
        $(".darkblue").removeClass("selected");
        $(".pink").removeClass("selected");
        $(".brown").removeClass("selected");
        $(".black").removeClass("selected");
        $(".white").removeClass("selected");
    });
    $(".darkblue").click(function(){
        $(".darkblue").addClass("selected");
        $(".orange").removeClass("selected");
        $(".yellow").removeClass("selected");
        $(".green").removeClass("selected");
        $(".lightblue").removeClass("selected");
        $(".red").removeClass("selected");
        $(".pink").removeClass("selected");
        $(".brown").removeClass("selected");
        $(".black").removeClass("selected");
        $(".white").removeClass("selected");
    });
    $(".pink").click(function(){
        $(".pink").addClass("selected");
        $(".orange").removeClass("selected");
        $(".yellow").removeClass("selected");
        $(".green").removeClass("selected");
        $(".lightblue").removeClass("selected");
        $(".darkblue").removeClass("selected");
        $(".red").removeClass("selected");
        $(".brown").removeClass("selected");
        $(".black").removeClass("selected");
        $(".white").removeClass("selected");
    });
    $(".brown").click(function(){
        $(".brown").addClass("selected");
        $(".orange").removeClass("selected");
        $(".yellow").removeClass("selected");
        $(".green").removeClass("selected");
        $(".lightblue").removeClass("selected");
        $(".darkblue").removeClass("selected");
        $(".pink").removeClass("selected");
        $(".red").removeClass("selected");
        $(".black").removeClass("selected");
        $(".white").removeClass("selected");
    });
    $(".black").click(function(){
        $(".black").addClass("selected");
        $(".orange").removeClass("selected");
        $(".yellow").removeClass("selected");
        $(".green").removeClass("selected");
        $(".lightblue").removeClass("selected");
        $(".darkblue").removeClass("selected");
        $(".pink").removeClass("selected");
        $(".brown").removeClass("selected");
        $(".red").removeClass("selected");
        $(".white").removeClass("selected");
    });
    $(".white").click(function(){
        $(".white").addClass("selected");
        $(".orange").removeClass("selected");
        $(".yellow").removeClass("selected");
        $(".green").removeClass("selected");
        $(".lightblue").removeClass("selected");
        $(".darkblue").removeClass("selected");
        $(".pink").removeClass("selected");
        $(".brown").removeClass("selected");
        $(".black").removeClass("selected");
        $(".red").removeClass("selected");
    });
});
```

In the JSFiddle it is working completely properly and is running and acting smoothly. Locally, it is acting very slow and all the CSS3 transitions are running choppy.

Can someone explain to me what is going on. If you want to check out the full code I have added it to [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=E1Ef0DtF).

Thank you so much for all the replies!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code is probably slow because you are creating 10 functions, creating 10 jquery object in each, and call 10 function inside each function.

Optimising you code seems a good move here.

Also, id's should be unique, so change the id `box` for a class.

In this case, i didnt changed it, and to have a working code, i had to select by attribute.

Your code can be reduced to this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("[id=box]").click(function(){
        $('[id=box]').removeClass('selected').filter(this).addClass('selected');
    });
})
```

Later, if you change you id for a class, selector will look like this `$('.box')`.

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/ErDgF/2/

Comment: Its invalid HTML to have multiple IDs in the same DOM. It will always retrive the first match

Comment: That's what i said : "Also, id's should be unique, so change the id box for a class.

In this case, i didnt changed it, and to have a working code, i had to select by attribute."

Comment: Thank you so much for this, although, it is still running very slowly! I don't know why! The JSFiddle is working nice and smoothly, but locally the run-time is extremely slow.

Comment: @Mitchell then, check the profil tabs in the chrome console to check what is slow. If you don't know how to use it, im pretty sure there's a lot of doc on the web! After, you'll know what is causing the slow.

Comment: @Mitchell, Just out of curiosity, what was it?

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon the images were way to high of resolution! Haha